# Python: Generate a new unique filename from a given filename

Tags: python, filenames

Suppose that I have a textfile `text.txt`. In Python, I read it to `lines` (which is a `str` object), make some changes to `lines`, and after that I want to save `lines` to a new file in the same directory. The new filename should be

- `text.new.txt` if it doesn't exist already,
- `text.new.2.txt` if `text.new.txt` already exists,
- `text.new.3.txt` if `text.new.txt` and `text.new.2.txt` already exist,

etc.

I came up with the following solution:

```
import itertools
import os

file_1 = r'C:\Documents\text.txt'

with open(file_1, mode='r', encoding='utf8') as f:
    lines = f.read()

# Here I modify `lines`
# ...

postfix = '.new'
root, ext = os.path.splitext(file_1)
file_2 = f'{root}{postfix}{ext}'
if os.path.isfile(file_2):
    for j in itertools.count(start=2):
        file_2 = f'{root}{postfix}.{j}{ext}'
        if not os.path.isfile(file_2):
            break

with open(file_2, mode='w', encoding='utf8') as f:
    f.write(lines)
```

I realize that I can use `while True ... break` instead of `itertools.count()` but it is essentially the same thing. I am wondering if there are any substantially better solutions to this problem.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to keep your code and your format is `filename.new.index.txt`, when you check that `filename.new.2.txt` exists you can check the last file with glob:

```
from glob import glob

# path contains path
filelist = glob(path + "\\filename.new.*")
last_index = max([filename.split(".")[-2] for filename in filelist])
```

And assign `last_index+1` as index for the new file.

For a more robust approach, consider applying str.zfill() to indices in order to sort them easily (i.e. 001, 002, 003...).